# How to use npm's 'events' module in Reactjs for eventEmitters

Tags: reactjs, npm, events, phaser-framework

I want to use npm's 'events' module in my React application. I have a game developed in phaserjs which also has level editor. The 'events' will used to communicate with the game module. 
  Folder Structure from root

- Client

  - src

    - App.js
    - index.js
    - Components/game-view
    - Components/level-creator-view
- Game
- Server

Some one had done same thing but in angular --
in it's app.js

```
const eventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter();
window.eventEmitter = eventEmitter;
eventEmitter.on('loaded', () => { console.log('\n\ncreator loaded\n\n') })
```

and in other states of his angular app he would just take --

```
const eventEmitter = window.eventEmitter;
eventEmitter.emit('start game');
```

[Here's the link to that project,](https://github.com/LanaCoyote/girder-gus-maker) look in browser module,app.js and also browser/states/createlevel

I want to do the same exact thing,my project is similar but game logic is different.

The game module has all the neccesary events emitters and listeners setup

I have tried setting up window.eventsEmitter() in my index.js and using that in other components. Problem starts here, how do I use it in a React class or a function,should it be in constructor or should I set it up in lifecycle methods,or should I put it completely different js file and include it? I tried most(except for last one) but failed.

I also searched about how to do it, haven't got exactly what I'm looking for..Any suggestion will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax for EventEmitter doesn't seem to work. I used the example from the npm page here (and it works) - 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/events

Add this to App.js:

```
const eventEmitter = require('events');
window.ee = new eventEmitter();
ee.on('loaded', () => { console.log('\n\ncreator loaded\n\n') })
ee.on('test', () => { console.log('\n\ntest fired\n\n') })
```

Then from any component constructor (or componentdidmount etc) :

```
constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    ee.emit('test', 'asdf')
}
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest method of implementing component communication for React JS 

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to create a file `eventEmitter.tsx` (in case you're using typescript):

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter()

export default eventEmitter
```

Then in any other file you can include this.

```
import eventEmitter from './eventEmitter'

const Hello = () => {
  const someFunction = () => {}
  useEffect(() => {
    eventEmitter.on('your-event', someFunction)
    return () => {
      eventEmitter.off('your-event', someFunction)
    }
  })
}
```